# Github secrets have '=' on the beginning of the value

Tags: github, github-actions

So I'm using github secrets in one of my github actions and I found a weird behavior. When I pass my secrets to a script like this:

```
      - name: Run script
        run: python script.py
        env:
          SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET=: ${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET}}
          SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID=: ${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID}}
          SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI=: ${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI}}
          SPOTIPY_CACHE=: "${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_CACHE}}"
          MAIN_TOKEN=: '${{ secrets.MAIN_TOKEN}}'
```

If I print the values of this tokens they all have a "=" appended on the start of the secret value. So if secret for `MAIN_TOKEN` is `12345`

```
print(os.environ["MAIN_TOKEN"])
```

Prints `=12345`

Is there any way to remove that = from being added to the secret value?

Comment: Why do you use `=:` instead of just `:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation about environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables), you shouldn't use `=` to set your variables based on your secrets in your workflow.

This is the correct syntaxe in your case:

```
  - name: Run script
    run: python script.py
    env:
      SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET}}
      SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID}}
      SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI: ${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI}}
      SPOTIPY_CACHE: ${{ secrets.SPOTIPY_CACHE}}
      MAIN_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MAIN_TOKEN}}
```

Note that you don't need to inform `"` or `'` if you get the variables from your secrets.